Excel - how dynamically select data in a table based on number of rows in a column
I have a table in which I draw a graph based on data from a column in another sheet in an excel spreadsheet
This is a simplified version of the actual data:

      A             

1     Col 1  

2     10                 

3     11        

4     12          

The data I am doing a graph of is on Col A, labelled Col 1
In a second worksheet I have a table to graph data in Col A,and in the table you set what data to graph by getting to the edit series part, and I then enter this to get the data:
=('Sheet1'!$a$2:$a$4)

This means that each time I add a row to Col A, I have to edit the above
What I would like to do is change this so that when I add a row to Col A, the graph automatically picks up this change
I've done various searches on how to do this, and it seems I should try setting up a filter called data, and set that filter to use an INDIRECT string like this:
=INDIRECT("'Sheet1'!A2:A"&D3)

where D3 is set to:
=LOOKUP(2,1/(NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))),ROW(A:A))

The above expression to set D3 works ok
And then in the edit series in the table use:
='Sheet1'!data

But I have not been able to get this to work.  I've tried various combinations etc.
Any advice/examples on how to do this would be appreciated

You may try =TOCOL(Sheet1!A2:A50000,1). If TOCOL() is not available then try the following formula in Sheet2.
=Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A50000,COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A50000))


Here Sheet1!A2:INDEX(Sheet1!A2:A50000,COUNTA(Sheet1!A2:A50000)) will return a array of values as well cell reference from Sheet1!A2 to last non empty cell in column A (Assume you do not have any blank rows inside data). If you have blank row, then you have to use different approach. See this post by @TheMaster


Thanks for reply, but suggestion does not work ( get invalid formula ), as in the real table, I do have blank cells in the column of data, I looked at that link, but as I mentioned in the post, I already have a way to get the row in the column that has the last cell with data.  Which leads back to how to use that calculated row value in the edit series selection in the table

As @rotabor said in his deleted answer - I'd use a data table.
Highlight your Sheet1!A1:A4 data and press Ctrl+T to create the table.

You can reference that directly in the chart using =Table1[Col1].
If you open the design of the chart again it will show =Sheet1!$A$1:$A$4, but will update when you add/remove data.


Or you can reference your table column in a second column using =Table1[Col 1].

Or use =FILTER(Table1[Col 1],Table1[Col 1]<>"") to remove blanks
or use =IF(Table1[Col 1]="",NA(),Table1[Col 1]) to replace blanks with an #N/A error so the series is left blank.
Next create a named range referencing your formula and the spilled results: =Sheet2!$A$1#

You can then reference that in your chart, remembering to use the sheet name as well (=Sheet2!MyData).  Charts don't like the direct reference to a spilled range which is why you put it in a named range:

